# Selenium WebDriver issues

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu, webdriver

In c# selenium WebDriver how do i verify that 'Yes' is displayed on a website page from a dropdown containing both 'Yes' and 'No'?

I have multiple drop down options on this page that contain yes and no. How do I specify the one i want?

I tried identifying the element used but that did not work

Comment: IWebElement directstreamOp = PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/fieldset/div[24]/select/option[2]"));
            //is this code right
            if (directstreamOp.Text== "No")
            //is this code right    
            {
                log.WriteLines("Passed");
                home.NavigateToSiteAdmin();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                home.NavigateToLogout();
                log.WriteLines("Logged out of the system");
                return true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SelectElement
    OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI

Сводка:
Provides a convenience method for manipulating selections of options in an HTML select element.
```

Take a look at Selenium Support UI (WebDriver.Support.dll)

```
SelectElement se = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.id("select_element_id")));
se.SelectByText("Item1");
```

Comment: Thank You vik. I will try and apply that now.